# Use DATE_ADDED instead of DATE_TAKEN when DATE_ADDED is 0 to sort a Query

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to request images and and sort them by DATE_TAKEN. In some cases `DATE_TAKEN` is not available.
In this case I would like to use `DATE_ADDED` as fallback.

Is it possible to combine this in a single SQL statement. I struggle bit but with this.

**My code so far:**

```
String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,

            MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,
    };


    String sortString = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + "  ASC";

    Uri target = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(target, projection, null, null, sortString);
```

**My idea would be something like this:**

```
String sortString = 
" CASE "+ MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN +" WHEN  "+  
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN +" ==  0 THEN "   + 
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED + " ASC " +
"ELSE " + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " ASC END";
```

But I've got an error and I don't even know if it is actually possible to do something like this.

**The error:**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ASC": syntax error (code 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASC applies to the entire expression used for sorting, so you must write it a single time:

```
CASE WHEN taken == 0 THEN added ELSE taken END ASC
```

Note: if you were using NULL instead of zero, this would be easier with [coalesce](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce):

```
COALESCE(taken, added) ASC
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. It solved my problem. I'm not sure if the value can become NULL. We add DATE_TAKEN as long ConentsValue to the MediaStore, so I assumed is never gets null. Also if we get the Value form the cursor we use getLong. Do you know more about that?

Comment: If you wanted to use NULL, it would be the responsibility of your code to store and read it, where appropriate.